# Most Pythonic way to find the sibling of an element in XML

Tags: python, xml, xpath

**Problem:**
I have the following XML snippet:

```
...snip...
<p class="p_cat_heading">DEFINITION</p>
<p class="p_numberedbullet"><span class="calibre10">This</span>, <span class="calibre10">these</span>. </p>
<p class="p_cat_heading">PRONUNCIATION </p>
..snip...
```

I need to search the totality of the XML, find the heading that has text `DEFINITION`, and print the associated definitions. The format of the definitions is not consistent and can change attributes/elements so the only reliable way of capturing all of it is to read until the next element with attribute `p_cat_heading`.

Right now I am using the following code to find all of the headers:

```
for heading in root.findall(".//*[@class='p_cat_heading']"):
    if heading.text == "DEFINITION":
        <WE FOUND THE CORRECT HEADER - TAKE ACTION HERE>
```

**Things I have tried:**

- Using lxml's getnext method. This gets the next sibling which has the attribute "p_cat_heading" which isn't what I want.
- following_sibling - lxml is supposed to support this but it throws "following-sibling is not found in prefix-map"

**My Solution:**

I haven't finished it, but because my XML is short I was just going to get a list of all elements, iterate until the one with the DEFINITION attribute, and then iterate until the next element with the p_cat_heading attribute. This solution is horrible and ugly, but I can't seem to find a clean alternative.

**What I'm looking for:**

A more Pythonic way of printing the definition which is "this, these" in our case. Solution may use either xpath or some alternative. Python-native solutions preferred, but anything will do.

Comment: Can you use BeautifulSoup?

Comment: I've used it before with HTML and if I had to refactor I could, but I was shooting for something a little more light weight since this is just a couple of lines. That said, maybe that's the better solution.

Comment: Just to clarify - is the expected output `This, these.  PRONUNCIATION`?

Comment: It should only be "This, these." Sorry again about that, should have picked a less generic Chinese character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing this, but by relying on xpath to do most of the work, this expression

```
//*[@class='p_cat_heading'][contains(text(),'DEFINITION')]/following-sibling::*[1]
```

should work.

Using lxml:

```
from lxml import html

data = [your snippet above]
exp = "//*[@class='p_cat_heading'][contains(text(),'DEFINITION')]/following-sibling::*[1]"

tree = html.fromstring(data) 
target = tree.xpath(exp)

for i in target:
    print(i.text_content())
```

Output:

> This, these.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BeatifulSoup with CSS selectors for this task. The selector `.p_cat_heading:contains("DEFINITION") ~ .p_cat_heading` will select all elements with class `p_cat_heading` that are preceded by element with class `p_cat_heading` containing string "DEFINITION":

```
data = '''
<p class="p_cat_heading">THIS YOU DONT WANT</p>
<p class="p_numberedbullet"><span class="calibre10">This</span>, <span class="calibre10">these</span>. </p>
<p class="p_cat_heading">DEFINITION</p>
<p class="p_numberedbullet"><span class="calibre10">This</span>, <span class="calibre10">these</span>. </p>
<p class="p_cat_heading">PRONUNCIATION </p>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for heading in soup.select('.p_cat_heading:contains("DEFINITION") ~ .p_cat_heading'):
    print(heading.text)
```

Prints:

```
PRONUNCIATION
```

Further reading

**[CSS Selector guide](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**

EDIT:

To select direct sibling after the DEFINITION:

```
data = '''
<p class="p_cat_heading">THIS YOU DONT WANT</p>
<p class="p_numberedbullet"><span class="calibre10">This</span>, <span class="calibre10">these</span>. </p>
<p class="p_cat_heading">DEFINITION</p>
<p class="p_numberedbullet"><span class="calibre10">This is after DEFINITION</span>, <span class="calibre10">these</span>. </p>
<p class="p_cat_heading">PRONUNCIATION </p>
<p class="p_numberedbullet"><span class="calibre10">This is after PRONUNCIATION</span>, <span class="calibre10">these</span>. </p>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

s = soup.select_one('.p_cat_heading:contains("DEFINITION") + :not(.p_cat_heading)')
print(s.text)
```

Prints:

```
This is after DEFINITION, these.
```

Comment: It needs to print the content of the definition though. The original code will iterate successfully over the headers - the problem is getting the contents beneath them accurately.

Edit: To clarify, the definition is the line with numberedbullet in it.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks man. I'm going to give it two or three days to see if anyone can come up with a way that uses the XML capabilities in Python. If not, I'll mark this one the answer and refactor the rest of the code to use BS.

Comment: Also I should have picked a word where the definition was more obvious. I picked Chinese 這 - this/these hahaha. Sorry about that.