# Confusion concerning def function to parse weird XML tree

Tags: python-3.x, xml, function, for-loop, xml-parsing

I was watching a Python for Everyone video by Charles Severance when I found a weird XML tree.

```
xml = '''
<dict>
    <key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Minor Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Date</key><date>2015-11-24T11:12:10Z</date>
    <key>Application Version</key><string>12.3.1.23</string>
    <key>Features</key><integer>5</integer>
    <key>Show Content Ratings</key><true/>
    <key>Music Folder</key><string>file:///Users/csev/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Music/</string>
    <key>Library Persistent ID</key><string>B7006C9E9799282E</string>
    <key>Tracks</key>
    <dict>
        <key>369</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>369</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Another One Bites The Dust</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>Queen</string>
            <key>Composer</key><string>John Deacon</string>
            <key>Album</key><string>Greatest Hits</string>
            <key>Genre</key><string>Rock</string>
            <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
            <key>Size</key><integer>4344295</integer>
            <key>Total Time</key><integer>217103</integer>
            <key>Disc Number</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Disc Count</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Track Number</key><integer>3</integer>
            <key>Track Count</key><integer>17</integer>
            <key>Year</key><integer>1980</integer>
            <key>Date Modified</key><date>2006-02-14T16:13:02Z</date>
            <key>Date Added</key><date>2006-02-14T16:12:53Z</date>
            <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>160</integer>
            <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
            <key>Play Count</key><integer>55</integer>
            <key>Play Date</key><integer>3518868190</integer>
            <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>2015-07-04T19:23:10Z</date>
            <key>Skip Count</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Skip Date</key><date>2015-10-14T23:31:47Z</date>
            <key>Rating</key><integer>100</integer>
            <key>Album Rating</key><integer>100</integer>
            <key>Album Rating Computed</key><true/>
            <key>Normalization</key><integer>1511</integer>
            <key>Compilation</key><true/>
            <key>Persistent ID</key><string>21130E105F3B8845</string>
            <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
            <key>File Type</key><integer>1297106739</integer>
            <key>Location</key><string>file:///Users/csev/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Music/Compilations/Greatest%20Hits/03%20Another%20One%20Bites%20The%20Dust.mp3</string>
            <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>4</integer>
            <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>371</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>371</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Asche Zu Asche</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>Rammstein</string>
            <key>Composer</key><string>Christoph Doom Schneider, Doktor Christian Lorenz, Oliver Riedel, Paul Landers, Richard Z. Kruspe-Bernstein &#38; Till Lindemann</string>
            <key>Album</key><string>Herzeleid</string>
            <key>Genre</key><string>Industrial</string>
            <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
            <key>Size</key><integer>4638526</integer>
            <key>Total Time</key><integer>231810</integer>
            <key>Disc Number</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Disc Count</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Track Number</key><integer>4</integer>
            <key>Track Count</key><integer>11</integer>
            <key>Year</key><integer>1995</integer>
            <key>Date Modified</key><date>2006-02-22T04:38:17Z</date>
            <key>Date Added</key><date>2006-02-14T16:13:04Z</date>
            <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>160</integer>
            <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
            <key>Play Count</key><integer>79</integer>
            <key>Play Date</key><integer>3518869000</integer>
            <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>2015-07-04T19:36:40Z</date>
            <key>Rating</key><integer>100</integer>
            <key>Album Rating</key><integer>100</integer>
            <key>Album Rating Computed</key><true/>
            <key>Normalization</key><integer>4576</integer>
            <key>Persistent ID</key><string>21130E105F3B8846</string>
            <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
            <key>File Type</key><integer>1297106739</integer>
            <key>Location</key><string>file:///Users/csev/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Music/Rammstein/Herzeleid/04%20Asche%20Zu%20Asche.mp3</string>
            <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>4</integer>
            <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>373</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>373</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Beauty School Dropout</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>Various</string>
            <key>Album</key><string>Grease</string>
            <key>Genre</key><string>Soundtrack</string>
            <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
            <key>Size</key><integer>4801377</integer>
            <key>Total Time</key><integer>239960</integer>
            <key>Track Number</key><integer>6</integer>
            <key>Track Count</key><integer>24</integer>
            <key>Date Modified</key><date>2006-02-14T16:13:26Z</date>
            <key>Date Added</key><date>2006-02-14T16:13:15Z</date>
            <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>160</integer>
            <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
            <key>Play Count</key><integer>48</integer>
            <key>Play Date</key><integer>3516380131</integer>
            <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>2015-06-06T00:15:31Z</date>
            <key>Skip Count</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Skip Date</key><date>2010-04-07T15:38:14Z</date>
            <key>Rating</key><integer>100</integer>
            <key>Album Rating</key><integer>100</integer>
            <key>Album Rating Computed</key><true/>
            <key>Normalization</key><integer>1401</integer>
            <key>Persistent ID</key><string>21130E105F3B8847</string>
            <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
            <key>File Type</key><integer>1297106739</integer>
            <key>Location</key><string>file:///Users/csev/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Music/Various/Grease/06%20Beauty%20School%20Dropout.mp3</string>
            <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>4</integer>
            <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
'''
```

I want to extract (1) the name of the songs, (2) the artists, and (3) the albums but the lines I want to extract from are preceded by another child, like a conjoined twins:

```
<key>Name</key><string>Name of the Song</string>
<key>Artist</key><string>Name of the Artist</string>
<key>Album</key><string>Name of the Album</string>
```

The goal is to extract the name of the songs and print it on the command line:

```
|Name:  Another One Bites The Dust |Artist:  Queen |Album:  Greatest Hits
|Name:  Asche Zu Asche |Artist:  Rammstein |Album:  Herzeleid
|Name:  Beauty School Dropout |Artist:  Various |Album:  Grease
```

The code (from the video) to get the result above is shown below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def lookup(d, key):
    found = False
    for child in d:
        if found :
            return child.text
        if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == key :
            found = True
    return None

stuff = ET.fromstring(xml)
all = stuff.findall('dict/dict')
print('Dict count:', len(all))
for entry in all:
    if (lookup(entry, 'Track ID') is None) :
        continue

    name = lookup(entry, 'Name')
    artist = lookup(entry, 'Artist')
    album = lookup(entry, 'Album')


    if name is None or artist is None or album is None :
        continue

    print('|Name: ', name, '|Artist: ', artist, '|Album: ', album)
```

The question is can anybody shed some light on how the `def lookup()` works?
What I don't understand are:

- Why do the function need to define `found = False` first?
- If I define `found = False` and followed by `if found : return child.text`, will it return the `child.text`?
- Followed by `if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == key : found = True`, does that mean if the value of the two conditions are fulfilled, the next step goes out of the `for` loop, change the `found` value to `True` and then goes back in the `for` loop and return `child.text`?

I tried to understand the code inside def lookup() by swapping some lines:

```
def lookup(d, key):
    found = False
    for child in d:
        if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == key :
            found = True
        if found :
            return child.text
    return None
```

and all I got was:

```
|Name:  Name |Artist:  Artist |Album:  Album
|Name:  Name |Artist:  Artist |Album:  Album
|Name:  Name |Artist:  Artist |Album:  Album
```

Comment: Hi, the `lookup` function appears to be grabbing the text from the sibling immediately following the matching `key` element. You could also use xpath https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56904167/most-pythonic-way-to-find-the-sibling-of-an-element-in-xml

Comment: Thank you for the xpath answer which I haven't learned it yet (will read on it), but I still don't understand the mechanism behind `for` loops in detail.

Comment: Your intuition that the XML is badly designed is 100% correct.  Each key/value pair should have been contained in an outer element.  As it stands, a single missing key or value element messes up parsing, whereas with a container element there would be no problem except for the incorrect pair.